# Javascript, looping a set of instructions (set timeouts)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop an animation which is essentially changing the background-position ever 150 milliseconds. It does not fade or anything, it just has to happen over and over again. But I can not seem to find a solution that loops these set of instructions.

```
setTimeout( function() {
        $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -47px');
    }, 150 );

setTimeout( function() {
        $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -94px');
    }, 250 );

setTimeout( function() {
        $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -141px');
    }, 350 );

setTimeout( function() {
        $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -188px');
    }, 450 );

setTimeout( function() {
        $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -235px');
    }, 550 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Also use a global variable to see where the background image is, rather than setting lots of timeouts...

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
var currPos = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    currPos = currPos-47;
    if(currPos < -235){
        currPos = 0;
    }
    $('div.arrow').css('backgroundPosition','0 '+currPos+'px');
}, 150);
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aUBNw/

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('div.arrow');
function tim(){
setTimeout( function() {
        div.css('backgroundPosition', '0 -47px');
    }, 150 );

setTimeout( function() {
        div.css('backgroundPosition', '0 -94px');
    }, 250 );

setTimeout( function() {
        div.css('backgroundPosition', '0 -141px');
    }, 350 );

setTimeout( function() {
        div.css('backgroundPosition', '0 -188px');
    }, 450 );

setTimeout( function() {
        div.css('backgroundPosition', '0 -235px');
    }, 550 );
setTimeout( function() {
        tim();
    }, 550 );
}
tim();
```

will simply call itself after it's completed

Comment: You can move $('div.arrow') outside the metods then you dont need to find that collection over and over again.